# ¿Qué sucede al crear un Action o Outlet internamente?

Tags: swift, swift2

Como dice la pregunta, quería saber qué sucede al crear un Action o un Outlet detrás de escena.

Una pregunta más con respecto a un método de 'view': 
El método 'subviews' devuelve las 'UIVIEWS' que contiene la vista que llamó la función, pero si no tengo ninguna vista no debería darme nil? Osea, no debería ser optional?

[image: segunda pregunta]

Comment: En vez de hacer una foto de la pantalla, mejor haz una captura de pantalla con ⌘(command) + ⇧(shift) + 4

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se instancia el `XIB` en cuestión, lo único que ocurre es que se crea una instancia de todos los `IBOutlet` que contenga para que te esté disponible en la clase. Sobre los `IBActions` se añaden los `targets` necesarios al igual que si utilizaras el método `addTarget(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector, forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)` de un botón.

Respecto a la segunda pregunta, siempre que sea posible hay que evitar hacer un unwrapping de propiedades optional y en este caso en concreto, toma más importancia aún. La propiedad `subViews` es importante que esté inicializada ni que sea con zero objetos ya que así puedes hacer `addSubviews` u otros métodos sin temor a un error en tiempo de ejecución. Además, relacionado con la primera pregunta, para los `XIB` es necesario que este inicializado para poder incluir todas las `UIView` que tengas en el `XIB`.
Y por último, mejor que no sea un `Optional`, menos trabajo para ti en tener que hacer comprobaciones de si existe o no...

Comment: Claro, pero recién haciendo unas pruebas, vi que el método 'subviews' me devuelve dls elementos cuando yo en mi 'view' principal no tengo ninguno.

Comment: Cuantos elementos te devuelve? Porque no debería devolver ninguno...

Comment: Me devolvió dos, ahora edito la pregunta y agregó una foto.

Comment: Entonces seguro que tienes alguna vista que es `subView` de la vista padre

Comment: En el código primero guardo las subviews y luego agregó un label; las subviews me tendrían que dar 0 pero me dieron 2

Comment: En la foto veo que tienes una `UIView` añadido a través de del `Interface Builder` y después añades la `UILabel` y esas son las dos vistas que te da...

Comment: Si pero el método lo llamo antes de agregar el label. Y al método subviews lo llamó con la view, por lo que no tiene lógica que me devuelva a ella misma

Comment: Pues es raro... ¿puedes subir el proyecto para verlo?

Comment: Mm a donde dices que lo suba?

Comment: Dropbox o similar

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Bifi1jRejMcThwTjlJZEhvS1k

Comment: Si no tengo acceso no puedo ver el código...